Yolov8 tracking multiple streams
I am using yolov8's tracking feature for 2 streams (2 videos). I load 2 separate models and infer it to 2 streams in the main thread. However, as two models share the same memory, the ids of the objects of the two models increase together. For example, in stream 1 the id is 1, 2, 3, 4, then the next object detected in stream 2 is 5 and so on. How can I make the 2 models work independently? Thank you!
Here is the example code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

model1 = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')
model2 = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/1.mp4")
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/2.mp4")

def draw_results(results, frame):
    body_boxes = results[0].boxes.xywh.cpu()
    if results[0].boxes.id is not None:
        boxes_output = []
        track_ids = results[0].boxes.id.int().cpu().tolist()
        for box, id in zip(body_boxes, track_ids):
            x, y, w, h = box
            x, y, w, h = int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)
            boxes_output.append([x-w//2, y-h//2, x+w//2, y+h//2])
        for box, id in zip(boxes_output, track_ids):
            frame =  cv2.rectangle(frame, (box[0], box[1]), (box[2], box[3]), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, str(id), (box[0], box[1]-15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
                        1, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    return frame

while True:
    ret, frame1 = cap1.read()
    ret, frame2 = cap2.read()
    
    results1 = model1.track(frame1, persist=True, iou = 0.5, classes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7], verbose = False)
    frame1 = draw_results(results1, frame1)

    results2 = model2.track(frame2, persist=True, iou = 0.5, classes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7], verbose = False)
    frame2 = draw_results(results2, frame2)
            
    cv2.imshow("Camera 1", frame1)
    cv2.imshow("Camera 2", frame2)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == 32:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

I tried inference in 2 different threads and the results remained the same.

Please add a minimal reproducible code example

Have you tried the proposed threading solution from Ultralytics docs? https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/track/#multithreaded-tracking

I tried it and the result still hasn't changed
